# Is there a concise way to cumcount string occurences in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, cumsum

[image: sample of my df]

I have a df that is in chronological order (oldest to newest) of UFC fights. Each row contains both fighters. How would I create two new columns:

col_a = cumsum of number of fights R_fighter exists in,
col_b = cumsum of number of fights B_fighter exists in

So as an example, in row 1000 of the df, I'd like a cumcount of the amount of times R_fighter occurs in the dataframe from rows 0 through 999.

I'm struggling to wrap my head around this without using a for loop of some kind.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume your dataframe is called df and is indexed 0 to n. Then you can use apply and value_counts to add the cumcount columns as follows.

```
def myct(row,col):
    return df[col][:row.name+1].value_counts()[row[col]] 

df['col_a']=df.apply(lambda row: myct(row, 'R_fighter'), axis=1)
df['col_b']=df.apply(lambda row: myct(row, 'B_fighter'), axis=1)
```

Comment: This is a nice solution. However, I seem to be getting some Key Errors when running it. If I flip the data frame using df.iloc[::-1] to make it reverse chronological (newest to oldest), I no longer get that error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.value_counts()`;

```
df['R_fighter'].value_counts()
```

Or `.groupby()` with `.size()`;

```
df.groupby('R_fighter').size()
```

**Note:** `.value_counts()` sorts the resulting `Series` in ascending order while the `.groupby()` method does not sort.

Comment: This only counts the values if they exist in each respective column. My solution would require the value count if the fighter name exists in EITHER column.